# ACCESS Too many fields defined

Tags: ms-access

Good Work Everyone.
There is a database with dbf extension given for Common Use. I can open the database with access and right click and delete the row, but when I want to delete it with a query, I get an error. error:Too many fields defined.
There are 457 columns in the table and unfortunately it is impossible for me to reduce the number of columns. I can right click and delete but why am I getting an error with the query, it's hard to understand

Comment: Show the query, show the error. The details are important.

Answer (score 0):

Access has a hard maximum of 255 fields ([source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c)).

If you can't reduce the number of fields, Access is not the right database for this data. It is odd that you can do anything with this table (dbf is also not an Access extension).

Comment: I'm developing a database intervention program with C#. SELECT, UPDATE Works, but I get too many field defined errors on DELETE

Comment: "It is odd that you can do anything with this table" - I seem to recall that if we try to create a linked table in Access and the target table has more than 255 columns then Access will just create the linked table with the first 255 columns and that will work (more or less) normally.

Answer (score 0):

> There are 457 columns in the table

There is no way Access can handle more than 255 fields in a table or query.

So, somehow get a tool that deals with *dBase* files directly and use this split the table into two, both having the primary key included.

Comment: Is there a tool you can recommend?

Comment: Sorry, no. I don’t work with dBase files.

Comment: @JİHATBERRAK- You could try opening the file in Excel. If that works you could save it to CSV or some other format.